# Create custom window with custom styles

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

My goal is to create a Window that when I use it I see my styles. I plan for this window to be the root of the view. So instead of using `<Window>` as my root I want to use `<MyWindow>`. My visual studio solution looks like:

[image]

1. I plan on using the following resource dictionary I named it **Styles.xaml**:

   ```
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"> 

     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" >
       <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Wingdings 3"/>
     </Style>

   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```
2. I want **MyWindow.xaml** to have that style therefore the I have:

   ```
   namespace ClassLibrary1.Style 
   {
       public class MyWindow : Window
       {
         public MyWindow()
         {
           // merge the dictionary
           var path = new Uri("/ClassLibrary1;component/Style/Styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
           var recDic = new ResourceDictionary();
           recDic.Source = path;
           var dic = recDic;
           // Clear any previous dictionaries loaded
           Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
           // Add in newly loaded Resource Dictionary
           Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dic);
         }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Now I want to use that window instead of the regular Window class. I then create a new window called **Window1.xaml** and it looks like:

   My Testblock

   - Note how I had to reference: xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ClassLibrary1.Style;assembly=ClassLibrary1"*

**Now why I only see the font at run time? How can I see the font that I specified at design time??** I have also placed:

```
this.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily("Arial Black");
```

in the constructor of **MyWindow** instead of merging the dictionaries.